# Trigger form validation on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCTf4VPkgooWL15iSfGL?p=preview) that displays a simple form with a required email field. The validation works when the user types in the email but is there a way to trigger the validation when clicking on the button. I don't want to disable the button based on the form validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're binding ng-show to data that changes whenever the user types. Instead bind it to data that changes when the button is clicked. Here's my take on it:

```
$scope.update = function(user) {
    $scope.isEmptyEmail = $scope.form.uEmail.$error.required;
    $scope.isInvalidEmail = $scope.form.uEmail.$error.email;
};
```

And then bind your data to these new values.

```
  <span ng-show="isEmptyEmail">Tell us your email.</span>
  <span ng-show="isInvalidEmail">This is not a valid email.</span>
```

Comment: Not very convenient if you have a lot of fields. But your approach works great.

Comment: @Sydney I agree completely. An actual validation solution provided via a directive or something similar would be the better approach if you plan to do a lot of form validation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have

in html:

```
ng-click="update(form)
```

in ctrl:

```
 $scope.update = function(form) {
    //form.uEmail.$error.email
    //..etc
    console.log('update');
  };
```

and continue validation

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach for myself. So far it seems to be working just fine

Controller:

```
$scope.update = function () {
    $('.ng-invalid').addClass('ng-touched');
    if ($scope.form.$valid) {
        /// submit
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ng-form name='form'>
    <!-- ... -->
    <button type="button" ng-click='update()'>Submit</button>
</ng-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a form validation, similar to above, but a little simpler and less code is:

```
<input id="id" type="text" name="inputName" required>
<span ng-show="isSubmitted && formName.inputName.$error.required">This field is required</span>
<button id="save" value="Submit" ng-click="formSubmission()">Submit</button>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.formSubmission = function() {
    $scope.isSubmitted = true;
}
```

This way, it can work with every field and you don't have to write code for every required input